# How to show correct pod version and pod page on cocoapods.org

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I support podspec NotifySDK. Now its version is 1.0.8 (published and available through cli).

#### Problems

- Cocoapods.org is sure that current version is 1.0.6 despite the fact that this version was changed more than 2 weeks ago.
- I absolutely don't understand what I should to do to show Pod page on cocoapods.org. Cocoapods redirects me to my site.

#### Attempts to fix

I tried to find answers on stackoverflow and on github but I can't. The most often recommendation is to wait but 2 weeks is enough time to update indexes.

During reading source of cocoapods I encountered few interesting things but they didn't help me.

- I found out that cocoapods.org > app.rb uses cocoadocs metrics for presentation pod info.

```
def metrics
  pods.outer_join(:github_pod_metrics).on(:id => :pod_id).join(:cocoadocs_pod_metrics).on(:id => :pod_id)
end
```

but cocoadocs is deprecated. Or not?

- Project cocoapods-metadata-service contains next string in README:
  `Downside: This will only work for Open Source projects on GitHub.`
  My project isn't opensource. But frameworks are available on github.com
- It seems to me that metrix are incomplete. Page http://metrics.cocoapods.org/api/v1/pods/NotifySDK shows github metrics without cocoadocs.

I would be appreciate for your help.

Also may be you can answer to next **questions**:

- Is there any way to force reindex podspec?
- Is there scheme of Cocoapods infrastructure?
- Is there any way to get database of cocoapods?

Comment: Have you been able to fix this? I cant get Cocoapods.org to properly index either.

Comment: Hi. I've relocated my frameworks to github. Also I've put files README.md, CHANGELOG.md and podspec to the root directory.    
    
These actions allows to me show correct pod page. But I can't fix change version of library in the list of pods.